# Peforming DML on a table by taking Excel file as an input

Tags: plsql

I am writing a PLSQL procedure that takes input as an excel file through front end and using that excel input the procedure inserts , updates or deletes the records present in an existing table . Can anyone show me the approach for this?

Comment: Thanks for your question. But please provide sample data and any relevant PLSQL even if it is incomplete. [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

If that "Excel" file has to be really in native XLS(X) format, a simple option - if you want to stay within Oracle boundaries - is an **Apex** application which offers a data loading wizard. Takes 4 pages to create it (don't worry, Apex Wizard creates almost everything for you). Once the loading is over, a (stored) procedure can do the rest of processing (you'd call it by pushing a button).

Alternatively, if you save contents of that file as a CSV file, you can load it with **SQL*Loader**, utility ran at the operating system command prompt. You'd have to create a control file (no wizard to do that, I'm afraid). This approach probably isn't convenient for end users (who's going to type *anything* at the command prompt?) so you'd have to create some kind of an application to do that.

Or, CSV again, but this time used as an **external table**. This approach requires the file to be located in a directory accessible by the database server (most frequently, the directory *is* located on that computer, and you most frequently don't want to allow access to anyone to it). Its advantage is that you can access the CSV file directly from (PL/)SQL, fetch data from it, perform various adjustments etc.

If you're capable of writing programs that aren't part of the Oracle niche (I'm not), go for it (but I can't suggest anything; someone else might).

Comment: Thanks little foot but as per my company standard I am not allowed to use SQL loader and apex application all I have to do is write a stand alone procedure to handle this. can you help me in this regard?

Comment: That would be the third option I suggested - external table. Though, as SQL Loader existed a long time before external tables were *invented* (and they are a complement to SQL Loader functionality), I don't quite understand what kind of a "company standard" is it. You use Oracle - one of its utilities is SQL Loader - you aren't allowed to use it. My opinion: your company should change its standard. Anyway: apart from what I've already said, there's nothing I'd like to add.